# Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code in ionic 5

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5, capacitor-plugin

We are migrating from Ionic 4 to 5, when I upgrade my mac version to 12 and try building the application we are getting *Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code* in two of the capacitor plugins **capacitor camera and capacitor file systems**
I tried most of the solutions like clearing derived data, adding a SWIFT_ENABLE_BATCH_MODE to no etc

Comment: Did you have any luck resolving this?

Comment: @MichaelButler This issue occurred due to some other plugin called capacitor-youtube-player, There the function invocation has less number of parameters than declaration, we resolved those using a patch and after that, it started working fine